# What's the difference between QMainWindow, QWidget and QDialog?

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, qtwidgets

What's the difference between QMainWindow, QWidget and QDialog?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

A `QWidget` is the base class for all drawable classes in Qt.  Any `QWidget`-based class can be shown as a window by showing it when it has no parent.

A `QDialog` is based on `QWidget`, but designed to be shown as a window.  It will always appear in a window, and has functions to make it work well with common buttons on dialogs (accept, reject, etc.).

`QMainWindow` is designed around common needs for a main window to have.  It has predefined places for a menu bar, a status bar, a toolbar, and other widgets.  It does not have any built-in allowances for buttons like `QDialog` does.

Comment: I searched for this question but that's not really the answer I was waiting for. In QtDesigner using a QMainWindow gives you a menu bar and a status bar. When you write the code yourself and use QMainWindow you don't have this things. Or your saying that you can do something like window.addToolBar("Toolbar"); and it will place it at a predefined place without any other headache?

Comment: @MoraruLilian: I don't actually use QMainWindow, so I don't know the particulars. As I said in my answer, I know it has places for them, so doing it in code might be as simple as you state.

Comment: @Caleb_Huitt It does what I am saying. I wanted just clear up if that's what you are trying to say. Anyway, I would recommend always using QWidget instead of QMainWindow. You can get into problems, for example with setting another Layout. If you want to set a new layout in QMainWindow you would have to create a QWidget and set it as a central widget for QMainWin and just then in QWidget you could setLayout(QLayout *). While you could avoid additional headaches just by using QWidget. Sure, QMainWindow offers that easy setup of the ToolBar and StatusBar but you can do that yourself in QWidget...

Comment: One reason we are looking to use `QMainWindow` instead of just the base class `QWidget` is that `QMainWindow` has `QDockWidget` support whereas `QWidget` alone does not

Comment: if I have a base class QMainWindow called calculator.ui, calculator.cpp, calculator.h, what does the constructor for derived class scientific_calculatror look like?

Comment: @mLstudent33 That sounds like a good question for documentation, and if that doesn't help, for asking here as a primary question rather than in the comments.  One example (for Qt5) can be seen at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html

Comment: I started experimenting just recently with QWidget and QMainWindow, I noticed that with QWidget, if I use QGridLayout the widgets I put in my window are placed nicely, while if I use QMainWindow the widgets that I add to the QGridLayout are placed one on top of the other...