# PyQt4: Difference between QWidget and QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

When reading through a PyQt4 tutorial, sometimes the examples uses `QtGui.QMainWindow`, sometimes it uses `QtGui.QWidget`.

**Question:** How do you tell when to use which?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Statusbar')    
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another code example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Show title', self)
        cb.move(20, 20)
        cb.toggle()
        cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        self.show()

    def changeTitle(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('')

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between QMainWindow, QWidget and QDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298792/whats-the-difference-between-qmainwindow-qwidget-and-qdialog)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`QMainWindow` is a class that understands GUI elements like a

- toolbar,
- statusbar,
- central widget,
- docking areas.

`QWidget` is just a raw widget.

When you want to have a main window for you project, use `QMainWindow`.

If you want to create a dialog box (modal dialog), use `QWidget`, or, more preferably, `QDialog`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not going to use a menu bar, tool bar or dock widgets, they are the same to you. 
If you will use one of those, use `QMainWindow`. And don't forget to call `setCentralWidget` to your main layout widget.